# Tablesorter datetime format dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm custom parser

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, datetime, tablesorter

I'm breaking my head over this for quite a while now. I have date times in the format dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm which are displayed in the tablesorter table in the 6th column. But I can't get it to order it properly.

Parser:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'dayMonthYearHHMM',
  is: function(s) {
      return false;
  },
  format: function(s, table) {
      var date = s.match(/^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])\-([a-zA-Z]{3})\-([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\s([0-1]?[0-9]|2?[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$/);
      var m = monthNames[date[2]];
      var d = String(date[1]);
      if (d.length == 1) {d = "0" + d;}
      var y = date[3];
      return parseInt(y + m + d + date[4] + date[5]);
  },
  type: 'numeric'
});

var monthNames = {};
monthNames["Jan"] = "01";
monthNames["Feb"] = "02";
monthNames["Mar"] = "03";
monthNames["Apr"] = "04";
monthNames["May"] = "05";
monthNames["Jun"] = "06";
monthNames["Jul"] = "07";
monthNames["Aug"] = "08";
monthNames["Sep"] = "09";
monthNames["Oct"] = "10";
monthNames["Nov"] = "11";
monthNames["Dec"] = "12";
```

And the tablesorter definition:

```
    $(function() {
      $('.tablesorter-childRow td').hide();

      $(".tablesorter")
        .tablesorter({
          theme : 'blue',
          sortList: [[5, 1]],
          widgets: ["zebra"],
          headers: {
            5: { sorter: "dayMonthYearHHMM" }
          },              
          cssChildRow: "tablesorter-childRow"
        })
        .tablesorterPager({
          container: $("#pager"),
          size: 20,
          savePages: false,
          positionFixed: false
        });
      $('.tablesorter').delegate('.toggle', 'click' ,function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:not(.tablesorter-childRow)').find('td').toggle();
        return false;
      });
    });
```

Any input would be very appreciated and thanks

Comment: sorry for the formatting, it's my first post

Comment: Instead of `match(...)`, use `split(/\D/)` for a vastly simpler regular expression, then parse to Date using `new Date(date[2], date[1]-1, date[0], date[3], date[4])`, then just sort as `a - b`. Also, `monthNames[date[2]]` will likely cause *parseInt* to return NaN.

Answer (score -1):

Most modern browsers know how to parse dates.

```
> new Date('31 Dec 2017 12:00:00')
//=> Sun Dec 31 2017 12:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

To ensure it works in more browsers (MS Edge), you'll need to replace any extra characters between the date parts with a space:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'dayMonthYearHHMM',
  is: function(s) {
      return false;
  },
  format: function(s, table) {
      var date = new Date(s.replace(/[\-., ]+/g, ' '));
      return date instanceof Date && isFinite(date) ? date.getTime() : s;
  },
  type: 'numeric'
});
```

Comment: "*Most modern browsers know how to parse dates*" isn't good advice. EMCA-262 specifies [*one format*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) that is required to be parsed, anything else is implementation dependent. Hence the strong recommendation to never use the built-in parser.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you.